# Data seeded with Mongoose not being saved in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to add some data to MongoDB using Mongoose, but I'm having trouble getting that data to save to my database. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V30Rpqi6kYE) tutorial on YouTube (~11 min), but I think the video might be using a different version of Mongoose.

Basically, I have a Product schema defined in a separate JS file, and I'm running a file called productSeeder.js by running `node productSeeder.js` in terminal with the Mongo daemon running. When I switch to the correct database and type `db.products.find()` into the Mongo shell, nothing is returned to me.

My productSeeder.js file:

```
var Product = require('../models/product');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/shopping');

var products = [
    new Product({
        imagePath: 'images/dummy.png',
        price: 9,
        title: 'a title',
        desc: 'some text'
    }),
    new Product({
        imagePath: 'images/dummy.png',
        price: 5,
        title: 'a title',
        desc: 'some text'
    })
];

var done = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    products[i].save(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        };

        done++;
        if (done == products.length) {
            mongoose.disconnect();
        };
    });
};
```

My product.js file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var schema = new Schema({
    imagePath: {type: String, required: true},
    price: {type: Number, required: true},
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    desc: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

Thanks so much, and happy holidays!

Comment: no errors in console? did you try using console.log or debugging the result value returned by the save callback, what does it contain?

Comment: No errors; I tried printing the result, it prints the correct Products.

Comment: Just added Product.find({}, function(err, products) { console.log(products.length) }) to my code, inside the `if done`; for some reason, the length increases each time I run the entire file, meaning the data actually is being saved? Would there be any reason the data isn't being returned to me in the MongoDB shell, then?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know if Mongoose has successfully been connected before you try to save the Products?

One thought could be that since the Db access is async, you're trying to save off items before the connection exists.

You could pass a callback to your connection or use an event listener and wrap your save functions in the connection callback.

```
mongoose.connection.on('connected', function(){
  //save products here
});
```

I've read of a few cases of Mongoose failing to save without error.

Edit: might be better to listen for `.on('open')` instead [(mongoose docs)](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/3.5.x/docs/api.html#connection_Connection).

Comment: When you are in the `mongo` shell and type `use shopping` and `show collections`, do you see the `products` collection? Could you post the Mongoose model code you're using? I couldn't find it in the repo tied to the YouTube vid.

Comment: Just updated the original post with the model code. When I type `show collections`, I see `Product`.

Comment: I know collections are case-sensitive...does `db.Product.find()` give you anything?

Comment: Oh, that fixed it! I thought collections were always lowercase and plural, so if I created a schema called Product, should the collection be products?

Comment: [Looks like it!](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) Mongoose will automatically lower-case and pluralize the collection name based on the model name, unless you override this behavior with a third parameter in `mongoose.model`: `module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema, 'products'); // db.products.find() would now work`

Comment: Hmm, strange how it created a collection called `Product` instead of `products` by default, since I never specified the third parameter. Thanks for all your help!